# How to get flexbox to make 2 rows?

Tags: html, css

I feel like I'm really close, but I just can't figure out how to get a second row and maintained equal margins.  I have the following:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The row needs a reason to wrap...you need to have the content be too wide for the row. At the moment you have nothing that woud cause that.

Comment: One option - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pJYywv

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, I came up with this based on your example: http://codepen.io/socketwiz/pen/xGBVqd  This also is a little responsive. When you get the browser narrow enough the rows become columns.  Thanks for your help.